# slow SerialPort write

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

A legacy app is taking 200-400 milliseconds to write a single byte to a SerialPort! I'd expect it to be almost instantaneous.

The app receives strings, processes them and sends back and acknowledgement with

```
mySP.Write("\x6");
```

I've eliminated physical factors. It's using XP and .net 2.0.
Baud rate is 9600.

What could cause this kind of slow performance? locking?

Comment: How have you eliminated physical factors? If you write a simple test application, is it as fast as you'd expect?

Comment: Yes I wrote a test app and it was <1 ms.

Comment: Are you using the `DataReceived` event? What if you use the synchronous `Read*` methods?

Comment: Are you testing the time of the first one or thousands? Also I've run into USB-Serial dongles that are slower than others. Not sure that slow....